# Filter by date in xslt for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to filter xml data using xslt version `2.0`

Here some example xml data (my data follow this schema)

```
<Messages>
  <Message time="2015-08-06 22:00:11" type="Success">A</Message>
  <Message time="2015-08-07 22:00:07" type="Success">B</Message>
  <Message time="2015-08-07 22:00:15" type="Success">C</Message>
</Messages>
```

I tried using this solution [XPath query filtering by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663262/xpath-query-filtering-by-date) which suggested I use translate to convert the dates into number but I am getting an error message (in Visual Studio) that says

> Missing required whitespace

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message[translate(@time, "- :", "") > translate('2015-08-06 22:00:11', "- :", "")]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are trying to use double quotes inside double quotes. Try changing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message[translate(@time, "- :", "") > translate('2015-08-06 22:00:11', "- :", "")]">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message[translate(@time, '- :', '') > translate('2015-08-06 22:00:10', '- :', '')]">
```

---

P.S. If you're using XSLT 2.0, why aren't you comparing the values as date-times?

Comment: How do you compare the values as data-times in XSLT 2.0, do you have a link?

Comment: @Dan See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-value-comparisons and also http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-dateTime-equal and following.  If this doesn't answer your question, post it independently of this one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue trying to use the following:

```
 <xsl:variable select="userCSharp:StringConcat("00")" name="var:v1"/>
```

It threw the "Missing required whitespace" error. For me the following solution worked:

```
 <xsl:variable select="userCSharp:StringConcat(&quot;00&quot;)" name="var:v1"/>
```

It cleared up the error and let my code compile.